# dynamic router link in vue not working in vue3 vite project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I have a list of market pairs that also make up the link for trading page. The selection menu has got a list of market pairs coming from a vue component called **AppMarkets.vue**. The function is as following (I have commented it cause it is not working at the moment).

```
 gotoMarketView: function(base, rel) {
      this.newmarket.base.ticker = base
      this.newmarket.rel.ticker = rel
      console.log("market selected going to trader view: " + this.newmarket.base.ticker + "/" + this.newmarket.rel.ticker);
      this.$emit("closeDialog");
      // window.location.href = "/traderview?base=" + base + "&rel=" + rel;
      //this.$router.push("/traderview?base=" + this.base + "&rel=" + this.rel);
      // this.$router.push({
      //   name: "TraderView",
      //   query: {
      //     base: base,
      //     rel: rel
      //   }
      // });
      // window.location.href='/traderview?base='+base+'&rel='+rel
      // window.location.href='/traderview/'+base+'/'+rel;
      //this.$router.push({name: "TraderView", params: {base: base, rel: rel}})
      //this.$forceUpdate()
      //this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)

      // this.forceRerender();
      // "http://" +
      //   process.env.VUE_APP_WEBHOST +
      //   // "localhost:8000/#/traderview?base="+
      //   ":8000/#/traderview?base=" +
      //   base +
      //   "&rel=" +
      //   rel
    },
```

The component is being used on the **App.vue** page which is the main menu as follows:

```
              <AppMarkets v-on:closeDialog="gotoMarket" :key="componentKey" />
```

The gotoMarket function in **App.vue** as follows which I have made static at the moment to a specific pair because base and rel does not work at the moment.

```
gotoMarket: function() {
      // console.log("Going to new market..." + base + "/")// + rel)
      console.log(this.componentKey)
      this.componentKey += 1
      this.dialog = !this.dialog
      
      this.$router.push("/traderview/RICK/MORTY");
      //this.$router.push("/traderview?base=" + base + "&rel=" +rel); 
      //window.location.href='/traderview/'+base+'/'+rel;
    },
```

I want the link to be dynamic according to the selection made by the user from the menu here is the live example you have go to the Markets menu button on the top right corner to see the pairs.

http://v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/dashboard

Comment: dynamic routes are set up in your `routes` definition, which you've not shown.  The [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) explains it all quite well.  Any dynamic route like `'/traderview/' + param1 + '/' + param2'` is defined in `routes` as `/traderview/:param1/:param2`

Comment: I have that specified already

Comment: It'd still be very helpful to show... With as many different `router.push` statements you have commented out, it's difficult to understand exactly which one matches what you're trying to do.  Walk us through an actual example with desired path and values (or possible values) you're working with.  From your description the clearest idea we have is that things just "don't work".  It'll be much easier to construct a solution based on a clearly defined example and problem statement.